# How to Display a Banner When Someone is Redirected from My Old Site to my New One

Tags: php, http-status-code-301

I have it set up right now that when someone goes to **oldsite.com** they are redirected to **newsite.com**. What I want to do is when they are redirected to **newsite.com** I want a banner to be displayed at the top of the page.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? I believe the best way to go about this is using scripts to say if someone is redirected from **oldsite.com** then show this banner, else do nothing.

What would be the best way of resolving this issue?

Comment: What has this got to do with HTML or CSS or Javascript come to that

Comment: Has *oldsite* time to open/execute? Or are the users immediately redirected (forwarded by the server) to *newsite*?

Comment: You're most likely looking for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'document.referer' method there is an article here showing how to use it and extended documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer

Example:
Get the referrer of the current document:

```
var x = document.referrer;
```

The result of `x` will be:

the last page in your browser history...

update: for some reason this question showed up in the javascript tagged questions. but hey this is one solution for doing it on the UI side